# Batch domain ping script

Tags: batch, script, cmd.exe, ping

I need script for windows which ask me for domanin name and than pings it over domains I specify in that script...

it might looks like

```
Please input your domain: google
pinging google.com REPLY
pinging google.eu REPLY
pinging google.cc REPLY
pinging google.xzy NOT REPLY
pinging google.co REPLY
```

Hope it is easy to do. I'm newbie in script languages. 
Thank you

Comment: We are not a script-writing service, but we do help with errors which questioners cannot understand: what have you tried, and what errors did you get?

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm sorry that my question looks that way .... all I need to do is multiply ping command several times, against different 1 level domain. Well, obviously what I've tried was ping google.com than ping google.cm than ping google.ru ... and my question is to make this proces automated... // yes, I've made research about this topic, but I will spend days learning functions or anything else required to write this ... hope I've explained this well. If you don't like it, please leave. If you have power to do that, please delete this post.Anyway I will look forward any constructive answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this to get you going:

```
@echo off
set /p site=Please choose site to ping: 
FOR %%T IN (com,eu,cc,xyz,co) DO (
  echo %site%.%%T:
  ping %site%.%%T -n 1 | FIND "TTL="
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 @echo No Reply
 )
```